# Nginx upstream https

Tags: nginx

I have problem using nginx reverse proxy

This is not working (i have ssl module and  this passes the config test but does not load)

Note: server1 and server2 have different certificates.

```
upstream test {
    server server1.com;
    server server2.com;
}

server {
    ....
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://test;
    }
}
```

But this works:

```
server {
    ....
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://server1.com;
    }
}
```

Any idea why isn't the first one working but the second one is?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test this, but try:

```
upstream test {
    server server1.com:443;
    server server2.com:443;
}
```

I seem to recall seeing something like this in another question here recently, but cannot find it now. The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server) suggests that an upstream server defaults to port 80, whereas your second example definitely uses port 443.